# Azure Mobile Services: Failover and Redundancy

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Services for a production mobile application. I am looking into failover configuration in Azure portal and can't find anything about it.

There is the "Traffic Manager" as described in the [Azure documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh744832.aspx). But in my understanding it only deals with VMs and Networking, not the Mobile Services.

My guess is: failover management is included in the mobile services by design. In other word, if one MS azure server crashes, my mobile service URL will be rerouted on another server automagically.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Availability SLAs are only guaranteed on the Standard and Premium tiers, see Support and SLA in: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/mobile-services/

Answer (score 1):

An Azure Mobile Services is tied to a single Azure region. So if your Azure region fails, you need to manually migrate to another Azure region. [Details can be found in Recover your mobile service in the event of a disaster](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-disaster-recovery/).